# how can I update app on App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I would like to know how can I update my app to new version 1.1 on AppStore?
Do I have to make new AppID and add new app in the same way as the old one?

Thanks for reply,

Also I want to ask what this mean in my app status?

**"Routing App Coverage File"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update an existing app, you need to use the exact same Bundle ID as the existing app.  Any other Bundle ID won't be an update, but a completely different app in the App store.